# Mmio stale data patched on hypervisor but vulnerable inside kvm guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, exploit

My hypervisor tells me that `Mmio stale data` is patched:

```
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:      Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
```

But when I check inside my kvm running linux `6.1.0-12-amd64`, I see this:

```
Mmio stale data:       Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT Host state unknown
```

The guest uses the host cpu with these additional cpu flags:
`md-clear pcid spec-ctrl ssbd aes`

If this means that i'm vulnerable, should i be worried? How easy is this exploit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is to be expected, even if you did the right thing: disabled SMT on the host.

So long as your guests do correctly determine the host is vulnerable, they will apply the mitigation that is (at this time, by some) believed appropriate for the single-thread case. Guests just will not be able to confirm that on their own, because it is not uncommon for the hypervisor to present separate cores while infact only offering shared resources.

Some hypervisors can [explicitly promise](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/i386/hyperv.html#hv-no-nonarch-coresharing) that they will ensure all sibling SMT threads are (statically assigned, not unsafely shared and) recognizable as such. Afaict this is only utilized by Windows guests. The Linux ["Host state unknown" message is hardcoded](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.7-rc1/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/bugs.c#L2609), without regard for [HYPERV_CPUID_ENLIGHTMENT_INFO.EAX BIT(18)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.7-rc1/arch/x86/include/asm/hyperv-tlfs.h#L124).

Comment: Yes so this basically means my guest is not vulnerable but it thinks it is, so it tries to apply at least some mitigation? Also, i don't fully understand the second half of your answer. Are you saying that leaving SMT enabled is okay as long as i assign a vm with a cpu core and its corresponding thread?